# How to plot several function calls in one figure

Tags: matlab, function, plot, matlab-figure

I made a matlab-function that plots a graph. When I call the function several times, I want it to plot all the graphs in one prepared figure. But instead my code opens with every function call the prepared figure in a new window with only one Graph in it.

My function looks like this

```
function myfunction(x,y)

if ~exist('myfigure')
    myfigure = openfig('myfigure.fig')
    assignin('base', 'myfigure',myfigure) 
end

figure(myfigure);
plot(x,y)

end
```

With the if-function I tried to prevent it from opening a new figure-window, when myfigure is allready opened. But it seems like Matlab just ignores the if-function for my surprise. Even the Assignin didn't help out. Although checking in the command window, showed that exist('myfigure') changes its value. 
I really don't know why the if-function is ignored by Matlab. Have you any suggestions how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is `exist` cannot see the previous figure, because it's handle is deleted when the previous call to the function was ended. My suggestion is as follow:

Pass the figure handle to the function, and also return it as output:

```
function myfigure = myfunction(x,y,myfigure)
if nargin<3 % if you pass 2 variables or less
    myfigure = figure; % create a figure
else
    figure(myfigure); % otherwise use the one in handle
end
plot(x,y)
end
```

Here a sample code for that:

```
x = 0:0.01:2*pi;
myfigure = myfunction(x,sin(x)); %first call
myfunction(x,cos(x),myfigure); % second call
myfunction(x,tan(x),myfigure); % third call...
```

Note that you only need to get `myfunction` output on the first call, then you can continue using it until you delete the figure.

Comment: Hello @EBH, on the first function call "myfigure" isn't open or defined. So this could not work for me. I now helped me out by omitting the figure code in the function. It has to be entered every time in addition with the function in this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's totaly what i was looking for. My upvote you maybe not see cause I have less reputation points. One remark for others: after "plot" in the function I had to add "hold on" and you migth not use tan(x) for testing cause it becomes infinite at x=0.

Answer (score 0):

The function `figure` that you used is probably why it opens a new figure.

What you might want to do is simply get the current axes and plot in it.

So your function would look like this

```
function myfunction(x,y)

myaxes = gca; 
plot(myaxes,x,y)

end
```

This would work if you only have one active figure and axes, if you have more than you mihgt want to pass the axes handle to the function.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer within a narrow time frame.

Comment: Your suggestion don't work for my problem cause I prepared a triangle diagramm to plot trinary Datasets and need thus more than the axes.